# How to know if the selected item has already been selected or not in the listview

Tags: android, listview

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
 }
});
```

Please help me, guys. Thanks to you.

Comment: The code you provided not good enough.  Please format your code correctly and prove comments of what your trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I want to prevent the multiple selection on a particular list item..

Answer (score 0):

create a Boolean array of same size as the listview and store the item click in it.

```
 private Boolean[] itemHasBeenClicked = {false};
```

then onclick

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
 //whatever code
 itemHasBeenClicked[i] = true;
  }
});
```